# How to submit multiple forms to a single query string

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, query-string

I have the following rails index page

**search/index.haml**

```
= form_tag search_path, method: 'get' do
  = text_field_tag :q, params[:q], placeholder: 'Search...'
  = submit_tag 'search'

= link_to 'testing', search_path(params.except(:controller, :action).merge(p: 'testing'))
```

entering the value "product" and submitting the form gives me this query string

```
http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=✓&q=product
```

clicking the link after submitting the form gives me

```
http://localhost:3000/search?p=testing&q=product&utf8=✓
```

Is there a way I can add another form and have it submit to the already existing query string like the way the link behaves?

The idea is to use the second form as part of the search aggregations/facets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the URL the same way you're creating the URL for the link:

```
form_tag search_path(params.except...)
```

...and change your field name from `q` to `q[]` so that Rails will understand that you're sending an array of values.

Then on the server side you will need to join those back together with something like: `query = params[:q].join " "`

Comment: that one replaces the old query string. I'd want to add the min and max price form as part of the search aggregations/facets.

Comment: `params` includes all the old query string, that's why you pass it to the path helper.

Comment: I tried adding a form with that path and passing "hello" give me http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=✓&q= hello

Comment: Oh, you're right, because it's overwriting the one and only `q` param. I've updated my answer.